# Those rows are out of bounds

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using a named range to work with a set of rows. It looks like this: chkBxs = Sheet11!A2:A9

When I run my code, I get a 'Those rows are out of bounds' message. Right before this message, is the following output, "Sheet.hideRows([0]) [0 seconds]".

Here is the code I am using:

```
    var boxes = sheet.getRange("chkBxs").getValues();//.getValues();
    if (ckbx.getValue().toString() == 'true'){
     boxes.forEach(function(r,i){
      Logger.log(i);
      if (r[0].toString() == 'false'){
        sheet.hideRows(i);
      }
    });

  }else{
    boxes.forEach(function(r,i){

      sheet.showRows(i);
  });
  }
```

The test sheet looks like this:

```
   A     B          C
1                   CKBX
2 FALSE hidden 3
3 FALSE vis 4
4 FALSE hidden 5
5 TRUE  vis 6
6 FALSE hidden 7
7 TRUE  vis 8
8 FALSE hidden 9
9 TRUE  vis 10
```

I've tried tinkering with the range, but no luck.

Edit:
I just changed the named range to Sheet11!A1:A9 and it works fine. But I need it to start at row 2, not row 1.

Comment: Try providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Insted of getRange use [getRangeByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangebynamename)

Note: This is a Class Spreadsheet method, not a Class Sheet method.